# Need to 404 "perl.exe"

Tags: security

I was told the below, from SecurityMetrics that this must be resolved. However, there is no cgi-bin or perl file in that path.

> When we perform the following
>   http://www.domain.com/cgi-bin/perl in
>   the URL it pulls a 500 internal server
>   error. Please direct this to a 404 not
>   found alone; otherwise, the
>   vulnerability appears valid.
>
> Perl.exe When we perform the following
>   http://www.domain.com/cgi-bin/perl.exe
>   in the URL it pulls a 500 internal
>   server error. Please direct this to a
>   404 not found alone; otherwise, the
>   vulnerability appears valid.

They also said:

> We do understand that it may not exist
>   but please have your site show that.
>   An internal server error does not
>   prove that the file doesn't exist. A
>   404 not found does.

How can I do that? I'm using PHP 5.2.9 / Apache 2.2 / Centos 4.8

Comment: You're going to have to look at your server log (both access and error) to see what it's doing when they hit that URL.  Where are you looking for `/cgi-bin/perl`? Check your ScriptAlias and make sure you're looking in the right folder

Comment: Lol - a 404 not found doesn't prove anything.

Comment: I hope you do understand that despite being told `this must be resolved`, it's really up to you whether you do or don't. I personally would because 500 is the wrong error to return but you're under no obligation to do the same.

Comment: Something is messed up on your server, it shouldn't be returning 500 errors for files that don't exist. The answers below might get you past this test, but it certainly sounds like something is really wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is with a `mod_rewrite` rule. Check this into your `.htaccess`

```php
RewriteRule /cgi-bin/perl.exe  - [R=404,L]
RewriteRule /cgi-bin/perl  - [R=404,L]
```

(technically `404` is not a valid response code for `mod_rewrite` to be sending out, but it works)

Comment: That didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Install [modsecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org/) and add the following rule:

```
SecRule ARGS perl.exe "phase:1,log,deny,status:404"
```

Not only will you "comply" with this audit (yeah I know), but you will have a full fledged WAF protecting you against [many issues](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_ModSecurity_Core_Rule_Set_Project) you *may* have in your application.

Comment: That didn't work either.

Comment: I did check the logs and see this:

ModSecurity: Access denied with code 500 (phase 2). Pattern match "perl" at REQUEST_URI. [file "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.user.conf"] [line "368"] [hostname "www.mydomain.com"] [uri "/cgi-bin/perl"] [unique_id "TXomXZPKQgIAAHSLIZAAAAAM"]

Comment: Did you configure modsecurity with the CRS (core rule set) or did you start with a "blank" configuration?